# How to limit the response's fields from woocommerce rest API?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

I need to limit the response's fields of woo commerce Rest API. For example. When I need to show the products of a specific category. I just need product id, image, and slug. So, I wanna get only specific fields. Any way to solve my problem?

Comment: I'm looking for the same. I just need all SKU`s from all products (about 5000).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter hook [woocommerce_rest_prepare_product_object](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api/blob/master/src/Controllers/Version2/class-wc-rest-products-v2-controller.php#L179) to adjust the response.

```
$wc_rest_api->get('products', array('category' => '1234', 'fields_in_response' => array(
    'id',
    'images',
    'slug'
) ) );
```

The argument `fields_in_response` is not there by default.
The following code must be placed on server-side (i.e. in functions.php) to work with it.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_rest_prepare_product_object', 'at_wc_rest_api_adjust_response_data', 10, 3);

function at_wc_rest_api_adjust_response_data( $response, $object, $request ) {

    $params = $request->get_params();
    if ( ! $params['fields_in_response'] ) {
        return $response;
    }

    $data = $response->get_data();  
    $cropped_data = array();

    foreach ( $params['fields_in_response'] as $field ) {
        $cropped_data[ $field ] = $data[ $field ];
    }   

    $response->set_data( $cropped_data );   

    return $response;

}
```